# Subtracting opacity in javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

This might be a dumb question but I can't get this super simple script to work. 
I need a button that will reduce opacity by .1. every time it is clicked.

I've tried all of these.

```
x.style.opacity-.3; //This doesn't work. Doesn't do anything.
x.style.opacity=.3; //This gives me an opacity of .3. 
x.style.opacity-=.3; //This gives an opacity of 0. Why?
x.style.opacity--; //This will give opacity of 0 as expected.
```

I even tried this:

```
var timesTen = x.style.opacity*10;
timesTen--;
timeTen/10;
x.style.opacity=timesTen; // This gives opacity of 0;
```

I would expect the answer to this problem to have something to do with a lack of understanding of the operators. But I've looked trough tons of arithmetic tutorials and they all seem full of integer examples that work perfectly fine for me. I've even copy pasted some of them and changed the numbers only to find that they stop working. I'm sorry if this is a noob question (As I am sure it is). Thank you

Comment: As a side note, you don't yet understand statements in JavaScript. `timeTen/10;` for example does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Thanks. On that note. I was a bit desperate. I started trying random combinations of anythings. Yes, some seemed rather senseless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested, you have to set opacity first, then you can read it to change it.

`​<div id="x" style="opacity:1.0">Hello</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

`​x.style.opacity -= 0.3;`

Because the above is not part of a standard (nor works in Firefox,) write as follows:

`document.getElementById("x").style.opacity -= 0.3;`

In the case of adding to the opacity, `parseFloat` is necessary, because string concatenation will happen otherwise. Or write `-= -0.3` :)

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I was looking at the wrong place for my error.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm not sure how to explain why (I searched a bit) but I see `document.getElementById` much more widely used to access elements by ID. There's also jQuery :)

Comment: @ojcruz It just occurred to me that if adding to the opacity you need to use parseFloat, because reading the css returns a string, and string + number concatenates into a clumped string.

Comment: Yeah. A couple of people suggested that. And oddly enough it's not necessary to get it working. I can use your code code (or even my original code) so long as I set the initial opacity inline. In fact I think most if not all the solutions in this thread actually work if the opacity is set inline. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

```
x.style.opacity = parseFloat(x.style.opacity) - 0.1;
```

Why do it so difficult?

Comment: I'd like to note that all of the CSS properties are exposed to Javascript as strings, so this is *almost* the right solution (should be ``parseFloat``, not ``parseInt``)

Comment: I think you meant parseFloat()

Comment: Thanks everyone. My code actually works too (Go figure). The problem was in calling a style sheet to set initial opacity. Inline css works fine though. I believe your answers work fine too after changing the styling to inline.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the `x.style.opacity` property doesn't exist at this time, it is just applied thanks to css. Here is a workaround:

HTML:

```
<div id="t" style="background: black; opacity: 1;">Hello</div>
<div id="c" style="background: black;">Hello</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById( 't' ).onclick = function() {
    // This works
    this.style.opacity = this.style.opacity - 0.1;
};
document.getElementById( 'c' ).onclick = function() {
    var opacity = this.style.opacity;
    // If the property exists, just decrement it
    if ( opacity ) {
        opacity -= 0.1;
    }
    // Else, set it (it will only be set once)
    else {
        opacity = 0.9;
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/xDFBY/

Comment: I tested on Safari and Firefox. I'm using Dreanweaver. This was not the nicest answer. I do apologize if my question was silly. It seems the issue is in setting the opacity as inline styling. Calling from a css sheet was the problem.

Comment: The answer was not sarcastic or something, sorry if you took it the wrong way.

Comment: I edited to answer your question. The jsfiddle url is the same.